# pagination Vue.js table and make search bar work across pages of table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a web app, backend using Django, frontend using Vue.js.

In one HTML page, I have a Vue.js table.
As there are 700+ rows in the table, this page loads very slow and the button part buttons could not be shown.
So I want to do pagination to this table to show the bottom buttons after initial loading.
I have tried datatable using jquery to do pagination, but it does not meet user's requirements. Also seems like jquery datatable go against with Vue.js table and it has to load twice so I give up datatable.
How could I do the pagination and make search bar work across pages of table?

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></script>

            <table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                  

                    <th>Tag course & Submit</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in filteredRows" :key="`title-${index}`">
                    <td  v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)">{{ row.title }}</td>
                   
                    <td><button type="button" class="button2" v-on:click="check( $event, row.title)">Tag & Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

<script>
        Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
        var book_rows = [{title: XXX];

        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:() => ({
                filter: '',
                rows: book_rows
            }),

            methods: {
                highlightMatches(text)
                {
                    if (typeof text === 'string' || text instanceof String){
                        text = (text?text:'None');
                        const matchExists = text.toLowerCase().includes(this.filter.toLowerCase());
                        if (!matchExists) return text;
                        const re = new RegExp(this.filter, 'ig');
                        return text.replace(re, matchedText => `<strong>${matchedText}</strong>`);
                    }

                },
                submit : function(){
                    this.$refs.form.submit()
                },

            },
            computed: {
                filteredRows() {
                    return this.rows.filter(row => {
                        const author = String(row.author).toString().toLowerCase();
                        const title = String(row.title).toLowerCase();
                        const searchTerm = this.filter.toLowerCase();
                        return title.includes(searchTerm) ||
                            author.includes(searchTerm);
                    });
                }
            },
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: I agree that you want to avoid trying to integrate jQuery with Vue.js in general, although it is possible.  If you haven't already, try searching 'vue.js datatable' for vue implementations.

Comment: I did not found a Vue.js datatable with a valid CDN to use in Django project